# Change Debian image disk before installing on BBB

Tags: linux-kernel, debian, embedded-linux, beagleboneblack, debian-stretch

I'm working with beaglebones black always with Debian, more time with "Debian 7.9 2015-11-12 4GB SD LXDE" but in the current time i start working with "Debian 9.2 2017-10-10 4GB SD IoT".

I would like to know if it is possible, and if so, how to do it. So my objetive is when i flash the eMMC of the BeagleBone Black with a new Debian image disk, this image already contains some modifications that I always do after installing a new image, like for example:

-set up a static ip on /etc/network/interfaces 
- and other little things

So the goal, is to know the best away (in Windows or Linux) open the image, do the modifications and build the image again, and ofcourse the programs to use.

Best regards,
David

Answer (score 1):

Either mount and modify the SD card.

Or boot from SD and modify the SD card.

Or if you want to flash the same image to multiple devices, then flash to one and modify it to your liking. Once done use the appropriate script in /opt to turn it back into a SD card /flasher.

Answer (score 0):

**1) Boot your Beaglebone from the SD card enabling EMMC flashing**

Plug the SD card and hold the boot button on the top right (near the SD card slot) and, while holding this button, insert the USB/power lead to connect the power. Keep holding the button until the LEDs start to flash.
(Complete info on http://derekmolloy.ie/write-a-new-image-to-the-beaglebone-black/)

**2) Make your modifications to the image on EMMC**

For example remove some packages, download updates, configure network interfaces, etc.

**3) Dump EMMC content to SD**

There are many ways to do this, but the easiest is to use the [beaglebone-black-make-microSD-flasher-from-eMMC.sh](https://github.com/RobertCNelson/boot-scripts/blob/master/tools/eMMC/beaglebone-black-make-microSD-flasher-from-eMMC.sh) script that should be already installed on the beaglebone or downloading it from Github.

**4) Remove SD card and repeat from Step 1) on another beaglebone**